# How do you get the Related To objects which appear when sending an Email?

Tags: email, email-template, tasks, event

When you send an email in Salesforce you can related it to an Object from a preset list, I'm wondering if anyones knows of a way anyways to find what this list is?

Comment: Are you referring to the UI that appears when you click the "Send an Email" button on the Activity History related list?

Comment: Yes @BarCotter, that drop down field. Is there a way to access that list or associate a property on an object so I know that it'll appear in that list?!

Comment: The [help for that page](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=email_send.htm&siteLang=en_US) doesn't help much, all it mentions is "_Optionally, choose another record, such as an account, case, or custom object, to associate with the email._"

Comment: @BarCotter Yep, I'm struggling to find any connection between this field and any other on an object, thanks for looking though

Answer (score 1):

You could get the list of objects in that dropdown via APEX:

```
map<string, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap       = Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.getMap();
for(Schema.SObjectField F : fieldMap.Values())
{
    Schema.describeFieldResult FR               = F.getDescribe();
    if (FR.isAccessible() && !FR.isDeprecatedAndHidden() && FR.getName().equalsIgnoreCase('WhatId'))
    {
        if (FR.getReferenceTo() != null)
        {
            for (Schema.SObjectType FRobjT : FR.getReferenceTo())
            {
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult FRobjR = FRobjT.getDescribe();
                if (FRobjR.isAccessible() && !FRobjR.isDeprecatedAndHidden())
                {
                    system.debug('@@ LOOKUP OBJECT: '+FRobjR.getName()+' ['+FRobjR.getLabel()+']');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @VarunC , how would implement this using the REST API if this is even possible?

Comment: You can query sObject Describe using REST API. The docs says that you can get all fields, URLS and child relationships using sObject Describe api call of REST API - [Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=resources_list.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fresources_list.htm|SkinName=webhelp) and [sObject Describe](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_describe.htm) ...

Answer (score 0):

The list will show standard SalesForce objects such as Account, Asset, Campaign, Case, Contract, Opportunity, Product and Solution. It will also display any custom SObject that has the `Allow Activities` option checked on it.

If you go to any SObject, click edit and then check the `Allow Activities` checkbox then that object will now appear in the **Related To** field.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to find this list using REST or SOQL?!

Comment: Yes, see the answer posted by @VarunC